# locking marks in VIM

Tags: vim

Is there anyway (internal or via a plugin) to prevent marks to be overridden ?
I mean a way so you can't set a mark if it's already used (I'm thinking especially of global marks).

I'm thinking of adding them in my vimrc or session, but I would prefer another way.

### Update

Don't send me a script to do it. I can do it myself, my question was more if there is a hidden way in VIM to do it or if I had to write a script myself. The answer is apparently no.

Thanks anyway to people who already sent me a script. I'll use them to write my own one (as the scripts sent are not exactly what I want)

Comment: Could you update your question with the use case you're trying to address by setting marks in your vimrc?  Many of the marks are buffer-specific, so setting them in your vimrc/session file doesn't make a lot of sense.  Also, Vim remembers marks across sessions so your metric of "don't set a mark if it's already been set" won't work very well.

Comment: I have a couple of file (mainly configuration files, or files with a complex path)  which I have a global mark on them (so not buffer dependant) (for example my ~/.vimrc is set to V). As I don't necessarily remember all the letters I have already use when I'm setting a new one, I would like to note erase mark which already exists. (My internal map works in one way, file -> letter, but not the easier way, So If I'm thinking of a file, I can remember which bookmark, but I don't know which marks are already used or free)

Comment: I don't think marks are the right tool for this... you could just map a command to open the files you want ie map <Leader>gV :e ~/.vimrc (you could add splits or whatever as you like).

Comment: I'm sorry but I think that's exactly what are global marks for. And that works perfectly well until I destroy them by mistake. It's far easier and quicker to type mV than having to edit my vimrc (which I am considering doint in the last resort as said in my question)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may remap the `m` with custom function:

```
let s:marks={}
function s:SetMark()
    let m=getchar()
    if type(m)==type(0)
        let m=nr2char(m)
    endif
    if m=~#'^[a-zA-Z]$'
        if has_key(s:marks, m)
            throw "Mark ".m."is arleady set"
        endif
        let s:marks[m]=1
    endif
    return "m".m
endfunction
nnoremap <expr> m <SID>SetMark()
```

This function will prevent you from remapping mark. That is how it works:

1. We define a dictionary, which keys contain already set marks (actually we could use a list, but dictionary should be a bit faster).
2. We define a function that:

   1. Pick next symbol. As `getchar` may return either a string or a character number, we must convert it back to string.
   2. Checks whether we are going to set a mark (you can have mark with name `a`, but not with name `%`). If you try to set mark `%`, it would be ignored by vim, so no need to keep useless keys. And no need to prevent you from using `m'`, `m[` and `m]` since we cannot prevent redefining them by vim itself.
   3. Checks whether mark in question was already set by this function, throws a error if it was.
   4. Returns text `mC`, where `C` is your mark name.
3. We define a mapping that uses this function returned value as `{rhs}`.

Note that this will not prevent somebody from redefining this mark by `normal!` (but not `normal` without a bang) command, `nnoremap` (but not `nmap`) mapping or something similar.

**UPDATE**: Modified version of s:SetMark:

```
function s:SetMark()
    let m=getchar()
    if type(m)==type(0)
        let m=nr2char(m)
    endif
    if m=~#'^[A-Z]$'
        let pos=getpos("'".m)
        if pos[1]
            echohl Error
            echon "Mark ".m." is arleady set. Overwrite?"
            echohl None
            let c=getchar()
            if type(c)==type(0)
                let c=nr2char(c)
            endif
            echo
            if c!=?'y'
                return "<C-l>"
            endif
        endif
    endif
    return "m".m
endfunction
nnoremap <special><expr> m <SID>SetMark()
```

Comment: I was more asking if they were already a script doing that somewhere, than asking someone to write it. Anyway thank you. My only concerns is that is doesn't work. (It doesn't check if a mark is defined but if it has been set within the session)

Comment: Cool, I might post it on the vim website, If you want to add any license beforehand.

Comment: @mb14 This is public domain since I do not want to bother myself with such small amount of code.

Answer (score 4):

You can prevent marks from being changed while you run a specific command.  See [:lockmarks](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#:lockmarks).

---

There isn't a way to prevent them from being overridden, but you could use a function that asks for the mark to use, informs you if that's already used, and prompts for another mark.

```
fun! SetMark()
    let mark = ''
    while mark == ''
        call inputsave()
        let mark = input('Mark to set (Enter to cancel)? ')
        call inputrestore()
        if mark == ''
            return
        endif
        if mark !~# '^[A-Z]$'
            echohl Error
            echo "Invalid mark name.  Must be a capital letter."
            echohl None
            let mark = ''
            continue
        endif
        let pos = getpos("'" . mark)
        if pos[1] != 0 " Used mark
            let fname = fnamemodify(bufname(pos[0]), ':~:.')
            call inputsave()
            let yn = input('Mark already set for ' . fname . '. Overwrite? (y/n) ')
            call inputrestore()
            if yn !~? '^y'
                let mark = ''
            endif
        endif
    endwhile
    exe 'normal m' . mark
endfun
nnoremap <F2> :call SetMark()<CR>
```

Comment: What I want is that mark doesn't do anything, if the current mark is already set.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much what I m looking for, I guess I need to mix your script with the ZyX one.

Comment: @mb14 here is this mix, see updated answer. Did not know, that `getpos()[1]` of unset mark is zero.