# Keep cursor in same position on duplicated line in vim

Tags: vim

I've added these shortcuts to duplicate a line based on the `:t` command, where `:t.` duplicates the current line onto the next line (keeps cursor on the second of the pair of lines), and `:t-1` duplicates the current line onto the previous line (keeps cursor on the first of the pair of lines).

```
nmap <leader>D :t-1<cr>
nmap <leader>d :t.<cr>
```

In both cases the command moves the cursor position to the beginning of the line that has been created. How can I keep the cursor in the same position it was on (e.g. 20 characters in from the start of the line) on the new line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
nmap <leader>D mayyp`a
nmap <leader>d mayyP`a
```

It starts by placing a mark called `a` (`ma`) on the current cursor position, then copy the current line (`yy`) and paste it below (`p`). After that, it goes back to the original cursor position with `` `a ``. The second mapping uses `P` instead of `p` to paste the line above the current one.

This should do what you’re expecting.

Comment: Thanks, that works! Only (very slight) issue is if I've already tied `a` to another mark. I could just use a key I rarely use for marks, but is there some kind of mark that is meant for cases like this, like a 'throwaway' mark or anything?

Comment: I don’t know, see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387321/locking-marks-in-vim). Vim [seems](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_marks) to have a special mark, which represents your last position, that you can jump to using `` but I didn’t find a way to make it work here.

Comment: m` and `` are probably better than ma and `a.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest solution is to use

```
:set nostartofline
```

Makes ex commands retain cursor column when possible, see h:nosol